# What is the difference between properties.OpenWeb() and properties.Web?

Tags: event-receivers

I am developing an event receiver, using the ItemUpdating event, and I noticed that the properties parameter has an "OpenWeb" method, with this description:

> Retrieves the Web site that is associated with the event that occurred.

while it also has a "Web" property, with this description:

> Gets the parent Web site of the list associated with the event that occurred.

what is the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only difference is that properties.Web is cached for the duration of the event (after the first access to it).

So properties.Web is implemented to check if it has a cached SPWeb if so return that if not call properties.OpenWeb() and cache the result.

Neither of them will cause a memory leak as they are created from an SPSite which is disposed at the end of the event

Comment: so.. i should always use Web, to avoid getting an SPWeb that's already cached? what's the point of having OpenWeb be public then?

Comment: OpenWeb is mainly for backwards compability. Web didn't exist in WSS 3.0

Comment: Why is OpenWeb not deprecated then?

Comment: SharePoint don't generally deprecate things just because there now is a better option

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786383/what-the-difference-between-spcontext-current-web-site-openweb-listslist

On the same line check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee724407.aspx

So using SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb(); is much more efficient.

Comment: i don't see that conclusion at all! the first link says _don't_ use OpenWeb, as it will leak memory, and the second link says nearly the same thing. Also, neither of those show a time where both OpenWeb() and Web are available from the same object.